# Is the facade of the Palace of the Parliament in Bucharest the largest surface used for projection mapping?

Tags: video, romania, construction

Claim from http://iMapp.ro:

> The artistic works of the participating teams will be displayed on the largest projection surface in the world – the facade of the Palace of of Parliament (23,000 square meters)

[image: Dog adoption ad projected onto the Romanian People's House]

I witnessed the event yesterday and it certainly was a massive [experience to behold](https://youtu.be/XGoJ9JAUotM), but one would imagine there are easily larger surfaces that *could* be used for projection mapping, such as [Mt. Rushmore](https://wskg.org/news/mt-rushmore-to-feature-projections-of-key-women-in-suffrage-movement/) or Half Dome.

The facade of the Palace of the Parliament has been used as a [projection](https://panasonic.net/cns/projector/casestudies/048.html) mapping surface since [2014](https://www.vice.com/en/article/z4q4bx/60000sq-ft-architectural-projection-mapping-commemorates-bucharests-555th), if not earlier.

Might the Palace be the largest *artificial* surface that *has been used* for projection mapping, as of September 2021?

Comment: If you're counting surfaces that *could* be used as a projection surface, but have *not* been, then the answer is trivially "no". I think it would be best to limit this just to surfaces that actually *have* been used as projection surfaces.

Comment: No hard data, but from aerial photos I suspect the Hoover dam has bigger area than this building. And it's not even wet. OTOH, this one probably has more space for the audience

Comment: @JohnDvorak: I have hard data. The Moon is larger than the Palace and is visible to more people. But the claim is clearly about surfaces *that have been used for projections*. The OP's mulling about Mt Rushmore is a strawman.

Comment: Is the question supposed also to be asking about a *public performance*? The location in my answer clearly is already functioning, but not in public to date.

Comment: Hoover Dam is also in IMAX

Comment: In the title and the body of your question, you are asking about the largest *projection **mapping** surface*, but your quote is about a *projection surface*. So, the question you are asking does not match the claim you are asking about. Which of the two is it? And if it is the former, can you show an actual *notable claim*?

Comment: @F1Krazy, John: clarified as such. Oddthinking: further narrowed down to artificial surfaces.

Answer (score 5):

The [Grand Coulee Dam spillway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Coulee_Dam#Spillway), at 550 meters long by 168 meters high, beats both the Bucharest Palace of Parliament and the Al Wasl Dome by a large margin (84000 square meters versus 23000 or 25000 square meters).  It's been used as a projection surface for both [conventional and laser light shows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_light_show_(Grand_Coulee_Dam)) since 1957.

Comment: Interesting find, though the laser show there ([2021 video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XwsaRq9bsY8)) is much more rudimentary than [the projection mapping in Bucharest](https://youtu.be/XGoJ9JAUotM).

Answer (score 2):

On 1st October 2021 the **Al Wasl dome** is due to open in Dubai.

One of the many reports about the projection dome is

[252 Christie projectors envelop Al Wasl dome in light](https://www.christiedigital.com/help-center/customer-stories/252-christie-projectors-envelop-al-wasl-dome-in-light/)

> Al Wasl dome features a trellis design, with pieces of a specially made projection screen material stretched tightly between each section. This creates a 360-degree, **25,380-square-meter** (273,188-square-foot) projection surface. Visible from both inside and outside, the dome’s projection surface is one of the largest 360-degree projection surfaces in the world. Given the dome’s vast surface area, selecting the right projectors was essential.

Note that the story says *one of the largest* projection surfaces, however it is larger than the **23,000 square meters** quoted for the Palace of of Parliament.

The [Expo 2020 Dubai event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expo_2020) was originally scheduled for 20 October 2020, but was postponed, so the screen *would have* been ready 11 months ago, but for Covid-19.

Comment: I am not clear whether the Bucharest projection is just for one night, but it would appear that, at the time of the projection in September, it may well hold the title.

Comment: @Oddthinking the story link isn't clear, but the projection at the time of writing was getting its final tuning. With less than 2 weeks before opening, I imagine the dome exists!